# Determining the inverse of the following function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

The function $f \colon \mathbb R - {2} \to \mathbb R \setminus \{5\}$ defined by $ f(x) =\frac{ (5x+1)} {x-2} $ is bijective. Determine its inverse function.

I have no idea how to do this problem. The way I go about such problems is usually, find the inverse $(f^{-1} (x))$ and plugging it into $f(x) $ to show that it equals $x$,  therefore it is bijective.

I am not really sure on how to find the inverse in this one because I cannot use partial fractions in this. Even a starting point would be helpful!

Comment: Why don't you do what you've done in the past, but rather than having $f^{-1} (x)$ you are solving for it. (ie solve for $f^{-1}(x)$ in $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x = \frac{(5f^{-1}(x)+1)}{f^{-1}(x)-2}$

Comment: Note that $f(x)=\frac{5x+1}{x-2}=5+\frac{11}{x-2}$.

Comment: But then my answer is coming out to be 1 when I plug it back in in f(x) not x.

f^-1(x) = (11/x-5)+2

f(f^-1(x)) = (5((11/x-5) +2 )+1)/(11/x-5) +2 -2
 
= ((11(5)/x-5) +11)/11(1/x-5) = 1

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to write $x=\frac{5y+1}{y-2}$, and then solve for $y$.

However, given what you know about the domain and range,  you might guess that the answer is of the form $\frac{2x+k}{x-5}$, then write down the equation $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ and solve for k.

Comment: That is extremely helpful! But I still don't understand how you made the leap to $$(2x+k)/(x-5)$$

I understand everything else..

Edit: Nevermind! Got it! Thank you!! 

PS - If you are reading this in the future and don't know how I figured it out. Basically the equation $$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$$ and $$k=f(f^-1(x))$$